# Why assertTrue() can be called without Assert.assertTrue()?

Tags: java, junit, assert

The assertTrue() method seems to be quite a normal static method like:

```
public static void assertTrue() {
    ...
}
```

but when it's called, it looks so strange:

```
Assert.assertTrue(condition); //Should look like this.
assertTrue(condition); //But in fact it looks like this.
```

Why?
And if I want to do something the same, what should I do?

```
public static class Logger() {
    public static void log() {
        ...
    }
}

Logger.log(someMessage); //Not cool
log(someMessage); //cool!
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `import static`? Look at your imports.

Comment: That's because of the static import. At the top of your class, you should have something like this: `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` This import allows you to just write `assertTrue()` instead of `Assert.assertTrue()`, as it will import all static methods to be used right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the top of your source code file and look at the imports. You should see something like this:

```
import static some.packages.Assert.assertTrue;
// or
import static some.packages.Assert.*;
```

This is a `static` import. Basically what it does is it makes your specified member(s) as if they are static members in your class, so you can call them without the class name!

This can be done with `Logger` too!

```
import static whatever.packages.your.logger.is.in.Logger.log;
```

Comment: yes sure this is a great answer. Can I do more than clicking the triangle? (with the hover message :this answer is useful). If so, I'd like mark it as a "best answer". Thanks again.

Comment: @cheny Actually, a similar feature also exists in C#, `using static`.